# Sudden incompatible type compiler errors

Tags: objective-c, compiler-errors

I'm trying to integrate [CocoaLumberjack](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaLumberjack) into a project that I inherited.  I've seen it work fine in the past with other projects, but for some reason, I'm getting several errors in CocoaLumberjack's code.  Examples include:

- Suddenly I'm getting "Assigning to 'void *' from incompatible type 'const char [1]'" compile errors on struct properties when passing in a C string.
- I'm getting warnings on C arrays of C strings saying "Conversion from string literal to 'char *' is depreciated.
- "class" has suddenly become a keyword (the lowercase version)

Has anyone ever seen anything similar to this?  The build settings on the project have definitely been changed a bit, but I'm not sure what was done.

Comment: Are you using a newer version of Xcode than before? They've been fairly aggressively ramping up the number of issues it detects by default.

Comment: I'm on the newest version of Xcode, but I've had it compile on this version before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any chance you're accidentally compiling the code as C++/Obj-C++? The third point there with `class` becoming a keyword makes that sound plausible.

Comment: It's definitely possible.  Is there any way I could check that?

Comment: @Ethan: Typically the language used for compiling is determined from the file extension. If it's `.m` it's obj-c and `.mm` is obj-c++. You can define custom mappings in the Build Rules section of your project, so you should check if you have any there. In Build Phases, in the Compile Sources phase, you can also check if there are any custom build settings on the files in question. You may also want to make sure you don't have some sort of target-wide or project-wide flag in your Build Settings that forces compilation as C++

Comment: For that final suggestion, I would look at any build setting that you've modified in the project (these are bolded in the Build Settings pane) and see if anything looks interesting.

Comment: Just looked and they had the "Compile Sources As" flag set to "Objective-C++" instead of "According to file type."  Setting it back fixed it.  Thanks a ton!

Comment: I am still facing this issue.. I have some c++ files in my project. So i have used Objective C++. But when u use Lumberjack i am getting errir'

Answer (score 0):

i have had this happen in vs, where the errors show up from newest to oldest as the compiler runs through the source code.Try to if your doing something like this always remember to trace to the first error and go from there.  I have had some pretty crazy results by putting a semicolon (;) after an include statment

ie

```
<string>;
<vector>;
```

will throw a crazy set of errors if it is in the wrong place.